# Python Compare value in list 1 with value in list 2

Tags: python, list, search, compare

I have created two lists in python list1 and list2.

I want to start at the first element in list 1 and search for that element in list 2  if it exists print something, if it does not exist print something else

I'm not sure how to march through list 1 and search list2 for value.  I know this will involve a for loop.

```
for in list1

if values =
print("True")
else:
print("False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for item in list1:
    if item in list2:
        print 'yes'
    else:
        print 'no'
```

Comment: We don't have enough information to know that.  OP said _I want to start at the first element in list 1_, which kind of implies that order might be important.

Comment: Again, we don't know that.  We don't know what's in list2, nor how it was constructed.  In the context of this small example it's not important, but OP might be simplifying.

Comment: Here is the full code.  Not quite working correctly. I'm not sure i'm doing my lists correctly as its only comapring the first element.

Comment: I gave you a working example.  What else do you need?